# Periodically refreshing the data in a DataTable()?

Tags: c#, .net

I am inserting data into a DataTable() using table.Rows.Add(Val1,Val2... etc)

the problem is this table updates in real-time and I need to update the table values. I also have a cell style listener on the container for the table which detects when the value of a cell changes.

I dont want to re-draw the table as I get run-time errors complaining about the table constraints. Is there anyway to re-populate the table?

On a higher-level of thought, I cannot see how to do this without deleting the rows and then re-drawing them because it's possible that on the datatable reload a previous row may no longer exist in the latest database grab?

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: the Java version of DataTable also has the same problem. It can be solved by synchronizing with the AWT thread to finish drawing the inserting/changing rows. Maybe you can do the same in C#

Answer (score 0):

If you use `{Binding}`'s you wouldn't have to do anything except update the data source and the table would be automatically updated.

Here is one example but if you haven't done any Binding before I'd recommend reading up on it first, it is very powerful.

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-database